# Kitchen start-up time takes 100 seconds

Tags: pentaho, apache-karaf

When I run a job with Kitchen.bat, the job takes 100 seconds to start and I find the following line in the logs:

**ERROR [KarafLifecycleListener] The Kettle Karaf Lifecycle Listener failed to execute properly after waiting for 100 seconds. Releasing lifecycle hold, but some services may be unavailable.**

Is there a way to speed up the job start-up time?

Thanks

Comment: KITCHEN_KARAF_TIMEOUT_SECONDS=20
put above value in kettle.property and see if it resolves the issue.

Comment: Thank you. I tried the suggested parameter but it didn't work